# What is a simple proof that something is np complete that does not use np completeness of something else?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, computer-science, computability, np-complete

What is a simple proof that something is NP complete that does not use NP completeness of something else? Every proof seems to reduce to something else being NP complete.

Comment: I wrote [a summary of the proof that SAT is NP-complete](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818217/proof-that-sat-is-npc/818360#818360).  Since this was the first problem proved to be NP-complete, the proof doesn't depend on reducing the problem to another NP-complete problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest example I know of is the cook Levin theorem which states that the Boolean satisfiability problem is NP-complete.
The proof is quite involved but basically involves trying model any problem as a series of true false decision problems>